# Height of a regular polygon in terms of amount of sides and length of each side

Tags: polygons

I am trying to find an explicit expression for the length of each side $L$ of a regular $N$-sided polygon if I want the total height of the polygon to equal some unknown height $H$. I want $L$ to be in terms of the unknown height $H$ and the number of sides $N$

Comment: One possible strategy: Both $L$ and $H$ are closely related to the radius $R$ of the circumscribing circle of the regular polygon. Can you represent a formula for $L$ and $H$ in terms of $R$ and trigonometric functions of $N$?

Comment: I am trying to find $L$ in terms of only $H$ and $N$. I believe that by introducing a new unknown $R$ it is only further complicating the problem

Comment: Well, actually it is not that bad as you might think of. Both $L$ and $H$ are linear in $R$, so you can immediately eliminate $R$ to get a formula for $L$ in terms of $H$ .

Comment: What is it height of a regular polygon?

Comment: The height is unknown variable